# Find words in random string

Tags: c#, string, search, char, words

I tried solving [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/53ijnb/20160919_challenge_284_easy_wandering_fingers/) problem however my output seems to have extra words in there which actually appear to be correct ?

For the following input I get this output :

> qwertyuytresdftyuioknn -> queen,quern,question,quieten,quinin,quintin,quoin

the answer on the questions says that the correct words are only **queen** and **question** but I dont see any problem with the rest of the words I see as my output where is the problem ?

```
    private static string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = @"qwertyuytresdftyuioknn";
        List<string> possibleWords = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].Length >= 5 && words[i][0] == input[0] && words[i][words[i].Length - 1] == input[input.Length - 1])
            {
                possibleWords.Add(words[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < possibleWords.Count; i++)
        {
            string tmp = possibleWords[i].Substring(1, possibleWords[i].Length - 2);
            bool foundWord = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.Length; j++)
            {
                if(!input.Contains(tmp[j]))
                {
                    foundWord = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(foundWord)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(possibleWords[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You also need the mapping of the QWERTY keyboard to solve this task

Comment: Only "queen" and "question" are correct because the other words would have to backtrack through the input string in order to construct them. Only those two words can be made with characters ordered from left to right.

Comment: There is a vagueness in the statement: derived words... But there are examples.